# Parsing gives xa0 instead of 6°C

Tags: python, scrapy, html-parsing

I tried scrapying using scrapy spider using on below website

```
scrapy genspider netweather_belfast https://www.netweather.tv/weather-forecasts/uk/10-day/2521~Belfast
```

when I inspected element for text displaying temperature, I tried below Xpath

```
//td[@id="mi1"]/text()
```

[html element displaying above temperature xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jobks.png)

the output I received

```
[<Selector xpath='//td[@id="mi1"]/text()' data='\xa0'>]
```

instead of

```
[<Selector xpath='//td[@id="mi1"]/text()' data='6°C'>]
```

Is there encoding issue? How do I enable it on scrapy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, data is loaded dynamically by javascript that's why you didn't get actual data only using scrapy. You need automation tool with scrapy something like selenium. Here I use SeleniumRequest with scrapy.

Example code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class CoinSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'temp'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.netweather.tv/weather-forecasts/uk/10-day/2521~Belfast'
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url=url,
            wait_time=3,
            callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
                'Min_Feel_Like': response.xpath('//td[@id="mi1"]/div/text()').get()
                }

    def spider_closed(self):
        self.driver.close()
```

Output:(As it is temperature, so the output may differ from mine to yours)

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.netweather.tv/weather-forecasts/uk/10-day/2521~Belfast>
{'Min_Feel_Like': '7°c'}
```